# Merge information from rows with same index in a single row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working to create a database from different existing ones. After merging the information I need from them I get some rows that were repeated in both of them.

`2018-11-22     Iraq    13984.75     3000.0  NaN`
`2018-11-22     Iraq    NaN          NaN     Heavy Rain`

Desired output:

`2018-11-22     Iraq    13984.75     3000.0     Heavy Rain`

Now I want to merge these into a single one. Almost every value as seen in the image are just present in one of the rows and the other one has NaN value in its place. So I would like to substitute NaN by the value in the other row. However, there might be values which are defined in both rows such as the ending date in this case where I would like to keep the larger one.

Is there a way to do this with pandas?

Comment: Please provide dataframes as text, not images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,4,50,5,np.nan],
         'C':[7,np.nan,9,4,2,3],
         'E':[np.nan,30,60,9,np.nan,4],
         'F':['s','d','f',np.nan,'r',np.nan]
}, index=pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=6))


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('ertyui'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,6,5,5,8],
         'C':[7,np.nan,9,20,2,3],
         'E':[8,np.nan,3,6,90,np.nan],
         'F':[np.nan,'d',np.nan,'f','r',np.nan]
}, index=pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=6))
```

First [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print (df)
            A     B     C     E    F
2011-01-01  a   4.0   7.0   NaN    s
2011-01-02  b   NaN   NaN  30.0    d
2011-01-03  c   4.0   9.0  60.0    f
2011-01-04  d  50.0   4.0   9.0  NaN
2011-01-05  e   5.0   2.0   NaN    r
2011-01-06  f   NaN   3.0   4.0  NaN
2011-01-01  e   4.0   7.0   8.0  NaN
2011-01-02  r   NaN   NaN   NaN    d
2011-01-03  t   6.0   9.0   3.0  NaN
2011-01-04  y   5.0  20.0   6.0    f
2011-01-05  u   5.0   2.0  90.0    r
2011-01-06  i   8.0   3.0   NaN  NaN
```

Then select only numeric columns with [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and aggregate `max` per index:

```
df11 = df.select_dtypes(np.number).max(level=0)
print (df11)
               B     C     E
2011-01-01   4.0   7.0   8.0
2011-01-02   NaN   NaN  30.0
2011-01-03   6.0   9.0  60.0
2011-01-04  50.0  20.0   9.0
2011-01-05   5.0   2.0  90.0
2011-01-06   8.0   3.0   4.0
```

For strings columns aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) - first non NaN value per group:

```
df12 = df.select_dtypes(object).groupby(level=0).first()
print (df12)
            A    F
2011-01-01  a    s
2011-01-02  b    d
2011-01-03  c    f
2011-01-04  d    f
2011-01-05  e    r
2011-01-06  f  NaN
```

Last join together and for same order of columns use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df11, df12], axis=1).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (out)
            A     B     C     E    F
2011-01-01  a   4.0   7.0   8.0    s
2011-01-02  b   NaN   NaN  30.0    d
2011-01-03  c   6.0   9.0  60.0    f
2011-01-04  d  50.0  20.0   9.0    f
2011-01-05  e   5.0   2.0  90.0    r
2011-01-06  f   8.0   3.0   4.0  NaN
```

Comment: That worked well for what I needed, just one question: is it possible to add conditions for the groupby function because I may only want to group if they are happening in the same country. In your example I will want to group `2011-01-01  a   4.0   7.0   NaN    s` and `2011-01-01  e   4.0   7.0   8.0  NaN` iff they share, for example, column A value.

Comment: @Javi Rando Then need `df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).set_index('A', append=True)` and then `df11 = df.select_dtypes(np.number).max(level=[0,1])
print (df11)` and `df12 = df.select_dtypes(object).groupby(level=[0,1]).first()
print (df12)` and last `out = pd.concat([df11, df12], axis=1).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (out)`. Now I am on pnone only, so not tested.

Comment: Sorry, and last `out = pd.concat([df11, df12], axis=1). reset_index(level=1).reindex(columns=df.columns)`

Comment: It is losing the index, in this case column A that was set as index in `df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).set_index('A', append=True)` how can I fix it?

Comment: @Javi Rando Index is not lost, only thete is appended column A to datetimeindex, so get MultiIndex.