# Get cumsum of grouped dataframe with merged information from different rows

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have the following challenge: having a dataframe

```
data1 = {
        'Product' : ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product1', 'Product4', 'Product5', 'Product6'],
         'Name' : ['Bayer', 'Sanofi', 'Pfizer', 'Bayer', 'Bayer', 'Bayer' ,'AstraZeneca', 'Company1', 'Company2', 'Company2'],
         'Region' : ['Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Asia', np.nan, np.nan ],
        'Country' : ['France', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  'India', 'Indonesia', np.nan, np.nan],
         'Amount' : [910, 200, 898, 12, 50, 13, 52, 250,260,270],
         }
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I would like to have a cumsum of orders (= sum of 'Amount' for each pair 'Product' and 'Name'). My approach is to groupby '['Product', 'Name']' and transform to a pd.series.

```
df1['Cumsum orders'] = df1.groupby(['Product', 'Name'])['Amount'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)

print('line ', lineno(), 'df1 with cumsum \n ', df1)
```

It results in

```
      Product         Name  Region    Country  Amount  Cumsum orders
0  Product1        Bayer  Europe     France     910            910
1  Product2       Sanofi  Europe        NaN     200            200
2  Product3       Pfizer    Asia        NaN     898            898
3  Product1        Bayer     NaN        NaN      12            922
4  Product1        Bayer     NaN        NaN      50            972
5  Product1        Bayer     NaN        NaN      13            985
6  Product1  AstraZeneca     NaN      India      52             52
7  Product4     Company1    Asia  Indonesia     250            250
8  Product5     Company2     NaN        NaN     260            260
9  Product6     Company2     NaN        NaN     270            270
```

But I want is to get unique rows for each 'Product' - 'Name'-pair which contains the information on 'Region' and 'Country' from different rows
I would expect:

```
    #      Product         Name  Region    Country  Amount  Cumsum orders
    #   0  Product1        Bayer  Europe        France  13            985
    #   6  Product1  AstraZeneca     NaN      India      52             52
    #   1  Product2       Sanofi  Europe        NaN     200            200   
    #   2  Product3       Pfizer    Asia        NaN     898            898
    #   4  Product4     Company1    Asia  Indonesia     250            250
    #   5  Product5     Company2     NaN        NaN     260            260
    #   6  Product6     Company2     NaN        NaN     270            270
```

In principle, another already answered question ([Merge information from rows with same index in a single row with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366441/merge-information-from-rows-with-same-index-in-a-single-row-with-pandas)) deals with this issue. But I can't select by 'non-numeric' dtypes in my dataframe, unfortunately. I am grateful for any hint.

Comment: You can `df.select_dtypes(object)`, no idea if it'll help your case but chances are most of your non-numerics are going to have `dtype:object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
        'Product' : ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product1', 'Product4', 'Product5', 'Product6'],
         'Name' : ['Bayer', 'Sanofi', 'Pfizer', 'Bayer', 'Bayer', 'Bayer' ,'AstraZeneca', 'Company1', 'Company2', 'Company2'],
         'Region' : ['Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Asia', np.nan, np.nan ],
        'Country' : ['France', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  'India', 'Indonesia', np.nan, np.nan],
         'Amount' : [910, 200, 898, 12, 50, 13, 52, 250,260,270],
         }
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

r = (df1.groupby(['Product', 'Name'])
        .agg({'Region':'first' , 'Country':'first', 'Amount':'sum'})
)

print(r)
```

Result

```
                      Region    Country  Amount
Product  Name                                  
Product1 AstraZeneca     NaN      India      52
         Bayer        Europe     France     985
Product2 Sanofi       Europe        NaN     200
Product3 Pfizer         Asia        NaN     898
Product4 Company1       Asia  Indonesia     250
Product5 Company2        NaN        NaN     260
Product6 Company2        NaN        NaN     270
```

Comment: Works great, many thanks! Just as a cherry on the cake: any idea how to keep the 'Product'-Name in line 2 (group name)?

Comment: use this : ```print(r.reset_index())```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you:

#### Example

```py
df1["Cumsum Orders"] = df1.groupby(['Product', 'Name'])["Amount"].transform("sum")

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(["Product", "Name"])

df1 = df1.sort_values("Product")
```

#### Results

```
    Product         Name  Region    Country  Amount  Cumsum Orders
0  Product1        Bayer  Europe     France     910            985
6  Product1  AstraZeneca     NaN      India      52             52
1  Product2       Sanofi  Europe        NaN     200            200
2  Product3       Pfizer    Asia        NaN     898            898
7  Product4     Company1    Asia  Indonesia     250            250
8  Product5     Company2     NaN        NaN     260            260
9  Product6     Company2     NaN        NaN     270            270
```

If I have answered your question to your satisfaction, then consider accepting the answer.

And Check `Amount` column should be drop or not ?

Comment: Many thanks. The answer works fine and is very flexible. I accepted the answer by @Laurent B, because he was faster and as it is an oneliner. But I really appreciate  your help and the alternative solution.